# How to handle different method calls from RxJava to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java

I have an android application that adds and removes from SQLite database. I wanted to know the best practice for the following.

When adding a new row to my table it can happen two different ways. 
1) Need callback to display snackbar (Main Thread)
2) Do not need callback (Background thread)

for the calls to number 1 I have method in DBhelper to return a completable so onSuccess i can display my snackbar.

for the calls to number 2 they are applied in an Observable that is handling multiple actions.

**So is it best to write two different methods for these calls (like shown below)? Or would it be just as easy to call my completable from scenario 2's observable?**

Here are the two methods in my SQLite helper class

```
 public Completable removeFavRX(Media media) {
        return Completable.create(subscriber -> {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            try {
                db.delete(MainConstants.TBL_FAV, MEDIA_PATH + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(media.getPath()) });
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
                subscriber.onComplete();
            }
        });
    }

    public void removeFav(Media media) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            db.delete(MainConstants.TBL_FAV, MEDIA_PATH + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(media.getPath()) });
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always better to avoid [code duplication](https://refactoring.guru/smells/duplicate-code). This would mean a solution where you are returning a `Completeable` from the repository would be a better choice.

If you're worried about the two use cases, where one requires execution synchronously on a background thread and the other is consumed as a callback you can always cause the `Completeable` to be executed synchronously  with [`Completable#blockingGet()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#blockingGet--).

Example executing synchronously on a background thread:

```
repository.removeFavRx(media)
    .blockingGet(); //be sure to catch an exception here if you need to
```

Example with callbacks

```
repository.removeFavRx(media)
    .subscribe( //...
```